# Hadoop Streaming in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, hadoop

I am running hadoop in Pseudo-Distributed mode and using hadoop streaming to do my map-reduce operations. But the problem is I keep getting **Streaming Job Failed** error message. Following is the log:

**stderr logs**

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "input/StdInOut.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
>    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
>    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:166)
>    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.configure(PipeMapper.java:63)
>    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:88)
>    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:64)
>    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
>    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:34)
>    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:88)
>    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:64)
>    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
>    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:354)
>    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:307)
>    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:170)
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
>    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
>    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.(ProcessImpl.java:81)
>    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:30)
>    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:453)
>    ... 20 more

I know it says *java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "input/StdInOut.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified* but the file is present both on the local as well as on hdfs on the same path.

Here is the implementation of my own mapper:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  string s;
  while ((s = Console.ReadLine()) != null) 
  {
    string[] words = s.Split(' ');
    foreach (var word in words) 
    {
      //Setting occurance of each word to 1
      Console.WriteLine(word + "\t" + 1);
    }
  }
}
```

and I am using this command to execute my job in ssh:

```
bin/hadoop jar contrib/streaming/hadoop-*-streaming.jar -input input/sample.txt -output output -mapper input/StdInOut.exe -reducer NONE
```

Any solutions?

Comment: And if i use -file input/StdInOut.exe then the error message changes to:  

**java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\tmp\hadoop-AliAmjad\mapred\local\taskTracker\jobcache\job_201010301748_0017\attempt_201010301748_0017_m_000000_0\work\.\StdInOut.exe": CreateProcess error=216, This version of %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whether you need a x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and then contact the software publisher**.

I tried with both x86 and x64 versions of my program but no luck...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error was actually the relative path for the mapper.

Comment: you have my upvote.  would you care to go in a little more detail on where the mapper was searching for the file?